# Issue converting timestamp(6) '31-DEC-99 12.00.00.000000000 AM' to character

Tags: oracle

I am exporting some data from a table in an Oracle database to csv files. All the date and time columns are timestamp(6). In the select statement I convert them with

`to_char(TERMINAL_ARRIVAL_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') as TERMINAL_ARRIVAL_TIME`

This works fine for all dates except for the default values 31-DEC-99 12.00.00.000000000 AM. These values result in an invalid date of 1900-01-00 00:00:00.000000.

Have I understood this correctly ? What is the correct way to convert this timestamp to character ?

What I expected was 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000000.
What it produced was 1900-01-00 00:00:00.000000

Comment: Why do you show "AM"?

Comment: `to_char` is indeed the correct way to convert from timestamp to string. And the format model seems right. What comes to mind: try `select dump(terminal_arrive_time) from <your_table> where terminal_arrival_time = to_timestamp('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` and report back with the result.

Comment: I could not reproduce this. If I define a timestamp as any of `timestamp '1999-12-31 00:00:00'`, `timestamp '0099-12-31 00:00:00'` or `timestamp '9999-12-31 00:00:00'`, and apply `to_char()` using your display format, I get expected results and never 1900. What is the actual source value? (using a 4-digit year, unless you are actually talking about [99AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AD_99), or a dump as @mathguy suggested)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - that is why I suggested to OP to use `dump()` to see what is actually stored - it is certainly none of the values you tried (as you found out).

Comment: @mathguy - I could not locate any records with your where clause. However I had earlier noted down the primary key of one record with the said timestamp and used that for the where clause instead. The following is the result: Type=180 Len=7; 119,100,1,0,1,1,1 what can you suggest from this ?

Comment: @rarpal - that date is actually 1900-01-01 00:00:00, so the value you are seeing in the query output is correct. In your post you said you get that value "from the default 9999-12-31" - clearly that is not true. Why you have a value of 1900-01-01 in your data is a separate question (how it ended up there, etc.) - but if that's the issue, you have a data problem, not a problem with the query itself.

Comment: @mathguy - perhaps I was not clear. In my table I have some records with the value 31-DEC-99 12.00.00.000000000 AM in the terminal_arrival_time column which is a timestamp(6) type. It appears that the front-end application that populates this table puts this value as a default when no other value is available. This value also happens to be the max value for timestamp(6) (please correct me if this is not the case). In any case I need to be able to covert this to string without loss of data in order to export to csv file, but I get an invalid date when I use to_char. is there any other function?

Comment: You were very clear, you are just contradicting yourself. You said, just two comments ago, that you couldn't locate any records where terminal_arrival_time has the value 31-DEC-9999. Now, I hope you are not **writing** it as 31-DEC-99; that will resolve to 2099 or perhaps 1999 (or even 0099), but in no case will it produce 9999. Also, the max value would have time component 11.59.59.999999999 PM, but I don't see how that is relevant. In any case, you found a row that produces the "wrong output" in the query; in **that** row, the stored value IS in 1900, not 9999. `DUMP()` doesn't lie.

Comment: The value I am getting when I convert to_char is 1900-01-00 00:00:00.000000 not 1900-01-01 00:00:00. That is my issue. Is there an option here for me to share a screen shot of my Oracle Develop output ?

Comment: Oh! I was totally blindsided by your repeated reference to 9999-12-31, which has absolutely nothing to do with your issue. I did miss the problem of the day being 0, not 1. That is shown clearly in the DUMP output, I just missed it. The problem is that somehow the date of 1900-01-00 (obviously an invalid date!) made its way INTO the database. The issue is that bad data already exists in the table; this can be fixed, but understand that there's nothing wrong with the query itself. Normally bad data shouldn't be able to get in, but sometimes it does.

Comment: In a direct-path insert, for example, Oracle doesn't check to make sure dates are valid. You **can** get invalid dates like 1900-01-00 that way. What to do? You must fix the data in the table first. Run something like `update <table_name> set terminal_arrival_time = timestamp '1900-01-01 00:00:00' where <primary key = the value you have>` (Note that it won't work to put a `terminal_arrival_time = timestamp '1900-01-00 00:00:00'` condition in `where`, since this will throw an invalid timestamp error! You do need to use the "known" PK.)